# How to put indexes of characters in a string in an array in java

Tags: java

I want to make a method that returns an ArrayList and takes two arguments, one is a string and other is a character. I want to put in ArrayList all the indexes of the characters if they appear in string argument. For example, if a first parameter is a String "hello" and other is 'l' the Array should contain 2 and 3

Comment: Iterate the characters in the `String` by index, if they match the desired value add the index to a `List`. Then return the `List`. Alternatively, use successive calls to `String.indexOf` to find the indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example:

```
class Converter {
    public static String convert(String b, char a) {
        ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
        String d = String.valueOf(a);
        for(int x = 0; x < b.length(); x++) {
            String current = String.valueOf(b.charAt(x));
            if(current.equals(d)) {
                c.add(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        }
        return c.toString();
    }
}

public class ChapterOneBasics{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{  
        Converter h = new Converter();
        System.out.println(Converter.convert("Hello", 'l'));
    }
}
```

What we do here is we create a variable that takes a String argument and a character primitive argument. We then create an empty array list that will take the string value of the index if the index of the String matches the character argument. WE then convert the character to a string. Next, we run a for loop so that we can iterate through each index in the array. We make the current string the value of the character of the that we are iterating through at the moment. If that string equals the string value of the character that we passed to the method as an argument, we add the index (x) to the array list. When our for loop is done, we return that array list. This will return [2, 3] if we pass the string hello as the argument.

I will say this, you SHOULD show your work and attempt to do the problem before posting the question. That will make it easier for us to help you. I explained the problem in detail for you because it is important that you show your work and at least attempt to solve your problem. Then you can learn.

Answer (score 1):

Some java code for you:

```
void Indices(String str, char c){
    List<int> list = new ArrayList<>(); // define list

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++){ // go through each char in str
        if(str.charAt(i) == c){ // if the chars match
            list.add(i); // add to list
        }
    }
    return list; // return list
}
```

Comment: pseudo code?  Looks like actual code to me.

Comment: @Shar1er80 you are right, just didn't bother with naming conventions or testing it yet. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot man, helped a lot :)

Comment: @DamjanVlaic no problem, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways you can solve this.  One is what @gkgkgkgk provides.  Here are two other approaches.

1. Utilizes a `while` loop and `String.indexOf()` as @ElliottFrisch mentions in his comment.
2. With `regex`, the pattern you would use would be the character you are looking for.

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String data = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        System.out.println("\'e\' is at indexes" + findIndexesWithWhile(data, 'e'));
        System.out.println("\'o\' is at indexes" + findIndexesWithRegex(data, 'o'));
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> findIndexesWithWhile(String data, char character) {
        ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int index = 0;
        while (index != -1) {
            index = data.indexOf(character, index);
            if (index != -1) {
                indexes.add(index);
                index++;
            }
        }

        return indexes;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> findIndexesWithRegex(String data, char character) {
        ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(String.valueOf(character));
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            indexes.add(matcher.start());
        }

        return indexes;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
'e' is at indexes[2, 28, 33]
'o' is at indexes[12, 17, 26, 41]
```